# Does no default constructor result in no move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

If a class doesn't have a default constructor as it should always initialize it's internal variables, would it follow that it shouldn't have a move constructor?

```
class Example final {
public:
  explicit Example(const std::string& string) : string_(
    string.empty() ? throw std::invalid_argument("string is empty") : string) {}
  Example(const Example& other) : string_(other.string_) {}
private:
  Example() = delete;
  Example(Example&& other) = delete;
  Example& operator=(const Example& rhs) = delete;
  Example& operator=(Example&& rhs) = delete;
  const std::string string_;
};
```

This class always expects the internal string to be set by a non-empty string and the internal string is copied between `Example` objects.  Am I correct that a move constructor does not apply here because if an Example was moved it would have to leave the string empty via a `std::move` call?

Comment: Well, as long as *clients* cannot create an empty (*"default"*) object when they're not supposed to, why shouldn't *you* (the library itself) be allowed to do so. Of course there's no problem with a default object flying around, as long as clients cannot directly construct it. And in general clients shouldn't assume anything about the moved from object anyway (apart from that it's destructible and most probably assignable). They don't know it's in some (otherwise hidden) default state, they just know it's moved-from.

Comment: I guess, this is what I'm getting at: once you have moved an object, what state should it be in? I have read that it should be in a 'valid' state, for example, no dangling pointers, etc but I have always implemented `move` constructors as leaving the object in the default state so that `moved_object == Object()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If a class doesn't have a default constructor as it should always initialize it's internal variables, would it follow that it shouldn't have a move constructor?

**No, I wouldn't say so**.

The fact of moving from an `Example` object and leaving it with an empty string should not be a problem here, because usually a client should not make any assumption on the state of a moved-from object, apart from the fact that it is legal.

This means, that clients can only invoke functions that have no pre-conditions on the state of their `Example` input. Notice, that normally *almost all* of the member functions of `Example` would have pre-conditions on the state of the object (i.e. `string_` must be a non-null string), but not *exactly all* of them.

For instance, the destructor of `Example` should not mind if `string_` is empty - why wouldn't it be allowed to do its job even in that case? The assignment operator is another common example - why would it not be allowed to assign a new string to `string_`?.

Under this view, leaving an `Example` object with an empty string is OK, because all that clients can do with a moved-from object is basically either re-assigning it or destroying it - and for these use cases, it should not matter whether `string_` is empty.

Therefore, **having a move constructor and a move assignment operator does make sense**.

Comment: It really depends on what he defines to be 'valid' states for the object. Having a move constructor that violates class invariant is not good, so if he documents as an invariant that the string is non-empty then he should not have a move constructor that violates that. However, that doesn't mean that he can't have a move constructor, only that it should maintain the invariant, perhaps using a dummy string value when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @bames53, you are correct in that the class I have in mind must not have an empty string, as it is used to pass around the 'path' into something.  If the `Example` always ensures that the `string_` is a valid 'path' then it makes things a lot simpler in multiple places because I do not have to valid input strings.  However, I guess I could implement a `move` constructor and leave the `string_` in an empty state and just check for that one condition in the validation.  The class I have in mind actually does the validation of constant strings using `constexpr`.